# adding a note under latex table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a code as below, and I would like to get rid of the extra space at the last column [image]. many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}




\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rlrrrrrrrr} 
%\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l*{9}{R}}
\toprule
& Country & Article.No. & \%Freq & SCP & \%SCP & MCP & \%MCP & TGC & TGC/t \\  
    \midrule
1 & Usa            &  83 & 41.29 &  64 & 47.76 &  19 & 28.36 & 8120 & 97.80 \\ 
2 & United Kingdom &  26 & 12.93 &  19 & 14.18 &   7 & 10.45 & 1024 & 39.40 \\ 
3 & China          &  14 & 6.97 &   7 & 5.22 &   7 & 10.45 & 421 & 30.10 \\ 
4 & Italy          &   7 & 3.48 &   5 & 3.73 &   2 & 2.99 & 125 & 17.90 \\ 
5 & India          &   6 & 2.99 &   5 & 3.73 &   1 & 1.49 & 354 & 59.00 \\ 
6 & France         &   5 & 2.49 &   2 & 1.49 &   3 & 4.48 & 206 & 41.20 \\ 
7 & Germany        &   5 & 2.49 &   2 & 1.49 &   3 & 4.48 & 491 & 98.20 \\ 
8 & Netherlands    &   4 & 1.99 &   2 & 1.49 &   2 & 2.99 & 502 & 125.50 \\ 
9 & New Zealand    &   4 & 1.99 &   4 & 2.99 &   0 & 0.00 & 142 & 35.50 \\ 
10 & South Africa   &   4 & 1.99 &   4 & 2.99 &   0 & 0.00 &  32 & 8.00 \\ 
        \bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{10}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Note: The table is sorted based on total number of Article.No. 
     \%Freq,  \%SCP, and \%MCP are the percentage of the total  Article.No., SCP, and MCP, respectively.} 

%\end{tabularx}
\end{tabular*}
    \caption{The most influential countries}  %he total number published articles
    \label{tab:Most-Cited-Countries}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you point out which space you mean. Between note and caption?

Comment: Between TGC and TGC/t

Comment: Now I see it. thanks for clarification.

Comment: The title of your post does not correctly reflect the actual question. You may want to be more precise in the title.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112208/2388

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to reconsider the spelling of the country labelled "Usa".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this solution, based on `tabularx, siunitx` and `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!hb]
\footnotesize
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX *{3}{S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.2]} S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=3.2]}
\toprule
& {Country} & {Article.No.} & {\%Freq} & {SCP} & {\%SCP} & {MCP} & {\%MCP} & {TGC} & {TGC/t} \\
    \midrule
1 & Usa & 83 & 41.29 & 64 & 47.76 & 19 & 28.36 & 8120 & 97.80 \\
2 & United Kingdom & 26 & 12.93 & 19 & 14.18 & 7 & 10.45 & 1024 & 39.40 \\
3 & China & 14 & 6.97 & 7 & 5.22 & 7 & 10.45 & 421 & 30.10 \\
4 & Italy & 7 & 3.48 & 5 & 3.73 & 2 & 2.99 & 125 & 17.90 \\
5 & India & 6 & 2.99 & 5 & 3.73 & 1 & 1.49 & 354 & 59.00 \\
6 & France & 5 & 2.49 & 2 & 1.49 & 3 & 4.48 & 206 & 41.20 \\
7 & Germany & 5 & 2.49 & 2 & 1.49 & 3 & 4.48 & 491 & 98.20 \\
8 & Netherlands & 4 & 1.99 & 2 & 1.49 & 2 & 2.99 & 502 & 125.50 \\
9 & New Zealand & 4 & 1.99 & 4 & 2.99 & 0 & 0.00 & 142 & 35.50 \\
10 & South Africa & 4 & 1.99 & 4 & 2.99 & 0 & 0.00 & 32 & 8.00 \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
 \item[\hskip -\fontdimen 2 \font]Note: The table is sorted based on total number of Article.No.
 \%Freq, \%SCP, and \%MCP are the percentage of the total Article.No., SCP, and MCP, respectively.
\end{tablenotes}
    \caption{The most influential countries} %he total number published articles
    \label{tab:Most-Cited-Countries}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

---

> [image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx,lipsum}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[h]
\small\tabcolsep3pt\belowcaptionskip1ex 
\caption{The most influential countries \label{tab:Most-Cited-Countries}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}rX@{}
S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.2]
S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.2]
S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.2]
S[table-format=4]
S[table-format=2.2]@{}} 
\toprule
& Country & {Art. No.} & {\%\,Freq} & {SCP} & {\%\,SCP} & {MCP} & {\%\,MCP} & {TGC} & {TGC/t} \\  
    \midrule
1 & Usa            &  83 & 41.29 &  64 & 47.76 &  19 & 28.36 & 8120 & 97.80 \\ 
2 & United Kingdom &  26 & 12.93 &  19 & 14.18 &   7 & 10.45 & 1024 & 39.40 \\ 
3 & China          &  14 & 6.97 &   7 & 5.22 &   7 & 10.45 & 421 & 30.10 \\ 
4 & Italy          &   7 & 3.48 &   5 & 3.73 &   2 & 2.99 & 125 & 17.90 \\ 
5 & India          &   6 & 2.99 &   5 & 3.73 &   1 & 1.49 & 354 & 59.00 \\ 
6 & France         &   5 & 2.49 &   2 & 1.49 &   3 & 4.48 & 206 & 41.20 \\ 
7 & Germany        &   5 & 2.49 &   2 & 1.49 &   3 & 4.48 & 491 & 98.20 \\ 
8 & Netherlands    &   4 & 1.99 &   2 & 1.49 &   2 & 2.99 & 502 & 125.50 \\ 
9 & New Zealand    &   4 & 1.99 &   4 & 2.99 &   0 & 0.00 & 142 & 35.50 \\ 
10 & South Africa   &   4 & 1.99 &   4 & 2.99 &   0 & 0.00 &  32 & 8.00 \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{10}{@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Note: The table is sorted based on total number of Article.No. 
     \%Freq,  \%SCP, and \%MCP are the percentage of the total  Article.No., SCP, and MCP, respectively.} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```